# show $\nabla f(\bar x) \geq 0$ and $\nabla f(\bar x)\bar x = 0$.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ be a convex and differentiable function and $\bar x$ is solution of this problem

$$\min f(x) $$

$$s.t \qquad x \geq 0 .$$

Then show $\nabla f(\bar x) \geq 0$ and $\nabla f(\bar x)\bar x = 0$.

I know that if $\bar x$ is solution of a optimizing problem then $\nabla f(\bar x) = 0$ but i can't prove this.

Comment: Do you know the KKT conditions?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik no.

Comment: Hint: Let $(e_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ be the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R^n}$. The function $g_i(t) 
= f(\bar{x} + t e_i)$ has derivative $\nabla f (\bar {x}) \cdot e_i $ at $0$. If that derivative is negative, is the function at a maximum? If it is positive, can we conclude $\bar{x}_i = 0$?

Comment: By $\nabla f(\overline{x})\geq 0$ do you mean every component is $\geq 0$?

Comment: I think you mixed some things together. Explicit optimality conditions over $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ are $\nabla_i f(\mathbf{\bar{x}})=0$ if $\bar{x}_i>0$  and $\nabla_i f(\mathbf{\bar{x}})\geq 0$ if $\bar{x}_i=0$, where $\nabla_i f(\mathbf{\bar{x}})$ is the gradient with respect to the $i$-th component. In compact representation: $\nabla_i f(\mathbf{\bar{x}})=0, \; \forall i$ **and** $\nabla f(\mathbf{\bar{x}})^T\mathbf{\bar{x}}=0$ (this is what you wrote). These conditions are derived from the KKT conditions @ViktorGlombik mentioned, and I can't see how you prove it without being familiar with KKT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrange function is $L(x,\lambda) = f(x)- \lambda^Tx$. The KKT conditions are

$$\nabla f(x^*) = \lambda^* \tag{1}$$

$$x^* \geq 0 \tag{2}$$

$$\lambda^* \geq 0 \tag{3}$$

$$(\lambda^*)^Tx^* = 0 \tag{4}$$

The last equality is called complementary slackness condition. From $(4)$ and (2), we have $$\frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x^*_j} = \lambda^*_j, \quad j=1, \dots, n \tag{5}$$ for which

$$\frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x^*_j} =0, \quad \forall j\colon x_j^*>0 \tag{6}$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x^*_j} \geq 0\quad\text{otherwise} \tag{7}$$ $(6)$ and $(7)$ refer to the case where the constraint is inactive and active, respectively.